# How do I solve I/O error 103 in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

So Basically I'm in College in the UK (So that's school for Americans (17 years old)) and I have to make a file handling project for my finals.
I have done most of it but it's the login screen that is weighing me down a lot. What I want from the program to do is read the username and password and log the people in. There can be 2 different outputs. If you type in "Staff" in the username and "warwickschool2013" in the username, the program takes you to the "teacher" side of the program where they can add in new users.

```
unit LoginScreen;
interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, jpeg, ExtCtrls;

type
  TfrmLogin = class(TForm)
    lblWelcomeLogin: TLabel;
    edtPassword: TEdit;
    lblPassword: TLabel;
    btnLogin: TButton;
    btnClose: TButton;
    lblCounter: TLabel;
    lblAttempts: TLabel;
    Image1: TImage;
    edtUsername: TEdit;
    lblUserName: TLabel;
    procedure btnCloseClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmLogin: TfrmLogin;


implementation
uses MainMenu, TeachersMainMenu, ViewEditTheData, Globals_Unit;
var
LoginDataArray: array of TLoginData;
counter: integer;
Password, username : String;
Count1, Count2 : integer;
Temp: TLoginData;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmLogin.btnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
var
SearchName : string[10];
SearchCode : string[3];
begin
  Password:=edtPassword.Text;
  UserName:=edtUserName.Text;
  btnclose.enabled:= true;
 if (Password = 'warwickschool2013') AND (Username = 'Staff') then
   begin
     edtPassword.text :='';
     frmTeachersMainMenu.show;
     frmLogin.hide;
     counter:= 0;
     lblCounter.caption := IntToStr(Counter);
  end
  else
   begin
     assignfile      (LoginDatafile,'C:\Users\NinjaBoffin\Desktop\Delphi\DataFiles\LoginData.txt');
     reset (LoginDatafile);
     LoginDatacounter := FileSize(LoginDatafile);
     SetLength(LoginDataArray, LoginDatacounter);
     edtPassword.clear;
     edtUserName.Clear;
     for Count1 := 1 to LoginDataCounter  do
       begin
          read(LoginDatafile,SingleLoginData);
          LoginDataArray[Count1] := SingleLoginData;
       end;
      closefile (LoginDatafile);

      //bubble sort
      edtUserName.Clear;
      for count1 := 1 to LoginDatacounter-1 do
         for count2 := 1 to LoginDatacounter-1 do
            if LoginDataArray[count2].UserName > LoginDataArray[count2+1].UserName then
           begin
             temp := LoginDataArray[count2+1];
             LoginDataArray[count2+1] := LoginDataArray[count2];
             LoginDataArray[count2] := temp;
           end;
//Linear Search (files getting ready)
begin
  SearchName := edtUserName.text;
  assignfile     (LoginDatafile,'C:\Users\NinjaBoffin\Desktop\Delphi\DataFiles\LoginData.txt');
  reset (LoginDatafile);
  LoginDatacounter := FileSize(LoginDatafile);
  SetLength(LoginDataArray, LoginDatacounter);
  edtUserName.Clear;
  //Copying to array
  for  Count1 := 1 to StudentCounter do
   begin
      read(LoginDatafile,SingleLoginData);
      LoginDataArray[Count1] := SingleLoginData;
   end;
  closefile (Studentfile);
 //The actual linear search
for  Count1 := 1 to StudentCounter do
 begin
   if LoginDataArray[Count1].Username = SearchName then
    begin
      assignfile    (LoginDatafile,'C:\Users\NinjaBoffin\Desktop\Delphi\DataFiles\LoginData.txt');
      reset (LoginDatafile);
      LoginDatacounter := FileSize(LoginDatafile);
      SetLength(LoginDataArray, LoginDatacounter);
      edtPassword.clear;
      for Count1 := 1 to LoginDataCounter  do
        begin
          read(LoginDatafile,SingleLoginData);
          LoginDataArray[Count1] := SingleLoginData;
        end;
        closefile (LoginDatafile);
        //bubble sort
       edtUserName.Clear;
       for count1 := 1 to LoginDatacounter-1 do
         for count2 := 1 to LoginDatacounter-1 do
             if LoginDataArray[count2].Password > LoginDataArray[count2+1].Password then
                begin
                  temp := LoginDataArray[count2+1];
                  LoginDataArray[count2+1] := LoginDataArray[count2];
                  LoginDataArray[count2] := temp;
                end;
   //Linear Search (files getting ready)
   begin
      SearchName := edtPassword.text;
      assignfile (LoginDatafile,'C:\Users\NinjaBoffin\Desktop\Delphi\DataFiles\LoginData.txt');
      reset (LoginDatafile);
      LoginDatacounter := FileSize(LoginDatafile);
      SetLength(LoginDataArray, LoginDatacounter);
      edtPassword.clear;
      //Copying to array
      for  Count1 := 1 to StudentCounter do
       begin
        read(LoginDatafile,SingleLoginData);
        LoginDataArray[Count1] := SingleLoginData;
       end;
       closefile (Studentfile);
      //The actual linear search
       for  Count1 := 1 to StudentCounter do
         begin
           if LoginDataArray[Count1].Password = SearchName then
             begin
               frmLogin.Hide;
                frmMainmenu.Show;
             end;
          end;
        end;
   end;
  end;
 end;
 end;
end;
```

If that is not the username and password you have to enter the password and username made by the teacher for you. This is in the teachers form and the file is "Logindata.txt".

```
procedure TfrmAddNewUser.btnAddNewStudentClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  assignfile (LoginDataFile,'C:\Users\NinjaBoffin\Desktop\Delphi\DataFiles\LoginData.txt');
  reset (loginDataFile);
  LoginDataCounter := FileSize(LoginDataFile);
  SingleLoginData.Username := edtNewUsername.text;
  SingleLoginData.Password := edtNewPassword.Text;
  //find where to store the record
  seek (LoginDataFile,LoginDataCounter);
  {...and put the record in}
  write(LoginDataFile,SingleLoginData);
  closefile (LoginDataFile);
  edtNewUserName.Text := '';
  edtNewPassword.Text := '';
end;
```

I'm getting a constant I/O 103 error and I don't know where it's from (It's in the login form)
So how do I fix this error? and will the login work?

This is my first time programming

Comment: Why are you using fixed length shortstring? Why are you using legacy Pascal IO? Why isn't your code indented properly?

Comment: Please take the time to [edit] your question to properly format the code so that it's legible. There's a lot of code there to wade through when it's extremely poorly formatted. Also, use the debugger. Set a breakpoint (click on a line in the `btnLoginClick` event and press F5, or click the blue dot in the left gutter of the code editor, then run your app with F9). When the breakpoint is hit, use F8 to execute each line to figure out where the error is being caused. Then, if you can't figure things out, you can post the *relevant portions of your code*, and we can try to help.

Comment: @ DavidHeffernan: I'm only using what i was taught :(

Comment: Code 103 is *file not open* as a websearch would have told you. Use the debugger to work out where it is being raised.

Comment: Your teachers have taught you bad habits.

Comment: For the formatting, [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21941733).

Comment: `assignfile (LoginDatafile,...); reset (LoginDatafile);... closefile (Studentfile);` - probably not what you meant.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm guessing I was taught bad habits! But then again we were doing pascal last year and this year delphi. So we weren't taught an "complicated" things.

Comment: @KenWhite : I've tried my best to format it to your ways, hope this makes more sense now

Comment: @500-InternalServerError : That has fixed one thing :D, but now it doesn't change forms. It just clears out the edit boxes and does nothing. I have added clear the edit boxes in there, but it should then "log me in". Instead it just clears out the boxes and does nothing

Comment: @ninja please don't expect us to debug your entire program. You asked about 103.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm Not :( I have other forms in which the sorting is working and a random test generator which marks student answers, only this is not working.

Comment: Looks like you've got your answer then, right?

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, because it a) is invalid - it's not the question you asked that people are commenting trying to help you solve, and b) because adding [SOLVED] to the question title and asking a new question instead is not how StackOverflow works. If you have a new question, create a new post and ask the new question. If you've found an answer to this one, either leave a comment to the person asking them to post an answer so you can accept it as correct, or post one yourself. Self-answering is [encouraged here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Thank You Guys for solving the problem (I/O error 103)
Turns out i was closing file that didn't exist
      
      Closefile (StudentFile)
When it should have been 
     
       Closefile (LoginDataFile)

Thanks to everyone who helped

and sorry for being unethical :(

Answer (score 6):

Thank You Guys for solving the problem (I/O error 103)
Turns out i was closing file that didn't exist

```
Closefile (StudentFile)
```

When it should have been

```
Closefile (LoginDataFile)
```

Thanks to everyone who helped

Answer (score 1):

I'm late for your finals, but maybe this can help for future projects.
You can use an approach based on name-values pairs and on TStringLIst object ability to load and save text files, so you don't have to care about files handles:

```
const
  MyFileWithPath='c:\.......\UserList.txt';

procedure AddUser(UserId,UserPwd: string);
var
  l: TStringList;
begin
  l := TStringList.Create;
  try
    if FileExists(MyFileWithPath) then
      l.LoadFormFile(MyFileWithPath);
    l.Add(Format('%s=%s',[UserId,UserPwd]));
    l.SaveToFile(MyFileWithPath);
  finally
    l.Free;
  end;
end;

function GetUserPwd(UserId: string): string;
var
  l: TStringList;
begin
  l := TStringList.Create;
  try
    l.LoadFormFile(MyFileWithPath);
    Result := l.Values[UserId];
  finally
    l.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You can complete this simple basic pattern implementing a value structure if more data field are required.